# Django python-rq -- DatabaseError SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, python-rq

I'm using the django-redis and django_rq frameworks to support both redis caching and redis background task processing for my Django application on Heroku. It's worked smoothly in the past, however now I keep getting a `DatabaseError SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac` every time one of my jobs get run.

I read that this error occurs commonly with Postgres in the  https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/postgres-logs-errors article, but it hasn't really been giving me anything useful for my python setup.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is solved by closing the DB connection at the beginning of each job.

For example,

```
@job
some_job():
    from django.db import connection
    connection.close()
    some_more_code()
```